# load LLama 2 on cpu

Tags: large-language-model, llama, ctransformers

i am trying to load LLama 2 model on my CPU using CTransformers and get this model_type not recognized issue. if you know how to solve it or can suggest another way to load the model on my CPU please let me know. thanks.

CODE:
from langchain.llms import CTransformers

llm = CTransformers(model="C:\Users\yalik\Downloads\llama-2-7b-chat.ggmlv3.q4_0.bin", model_type="LLama")
print(llm("hello LLama"))

error:

Model type 'LLama' is not supported.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\LLama-2-poc\p,py.py", line 3, in 
llm = CTransformers(model="C:\Users\yalik\Downloads\llama-2-7b-chat.ggmlv3.q4_0.bin", model_type="LLama")
File "C:\Users\yalik\Desktop\lib\site-packages\langchain_core\load\serializable.py", line 97, in **init**
super().**init**(**kwargs)
File "C:\Users\yalik\Desktop\lib\site-packages\pydantic\v1\main.py", line 339, in **init**
values, fields_set, validation_error = validate_model(**pydantic_self**.**class**, data)
File "C:\Users\yalik\Desktop\lib\site-packages\pydantic\v1\main.py", line 1102, in validate_model
values = validator(cls_, values)
File "C:\Users\yalik\Desktop\lib\site-packages\langchain_community\llms\ctransformers.py", line 72, in validate_environment
values["client"] = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
File "C:\Users\yalik\Desktop\lib\site-packages\ctransformers\hub.py", line 175, in from_pretrained
llm = LLM(
File "C:\Users\yalik\Desktop\lib\site-packages\ctransformers\llm.py", line 253, in **init**
raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: Failed to create LLM 'LLama' from 'C:\Users\yalik\Downloads\llama-2-7b-chat.ggmlv3.q4_0.bin'.

Process finished with exit code 1